# Ado.Net entity framework, linq: select multiples tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I use these sentence in C# to retrieve data from tables DetalleContenido and Archivo:

```
var detallesContenido =
   from contenido in guiaContext.Contenido
      where contenido.PuntoInteres.id_punto == puntoInteresID
   from dc in contenido.DetalleContenido
      where dc.Idioma.ds_idioma == idiomaCliente
  select dc;
```

The relationship between tables is this:

[image: DataBase Model]

I use puntoInteresID and idiomaCliente to retrieve all rows from DetalleContenido and Archivo that are part of PuntoInteres but whith this sentence Archivo is allways null!!

The sql sentece equivalence is:

```
Select dc.ds_nomDetContenido, dc.ds_descDetContenido, ar.archivo
from Contenido c, DetalleContenido dc, Archivo ar, Idioma i
where c.id_punto = puntoInteresID
  and c.id_contenido = dc.id_contenido
  and dc.id_idioma = i.id_idioma
  and i.ds_idioma = idiomaCliente
  and dc.id_archivo = ar.id_archivo;
```

How can I retrieve Archivo too?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do

```
.Load()
```

on the "reference" properity of the selected object (when you are using them).

But as for your query, it seems your Archivo table is a 1 to many and you cannot "include" or "load" the "many" side of the equasion.  You would have to do a "select dc.Archivo" I would think.

Comment: You are right. I use select new {dc, dc.Archivo} to obtain the table Archivo.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the Include() statement? I think it would look something like this

```
var detallesContenido =
       from contenido in guiaContext.Contenido.Include("DetalleContenido")
          where contenido.PuntoInteres.id_punto == puntoInteresID
       from dc in contenido.DetalleContenido
          where dc.Idioma.ds_idioma == idiomaCliente
      select dc;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var detallesContenido =
  from contenido in guiaContext.Contenido
      where contenido.PuntoInteres.id_punto == puntoInteresID && contenido.DetalleContenido.Any(c=>c.Idioma.ds_idioma == idiomaCliente)
  select contenido.DetalleContenido;
```

Comment: I want to retrieve DetalleContenido AND Archivo.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
var detallesContenido =
   from contenido in guiaContext.Contenido
      where contenido.PuntoInteres.id_punto == puntoInteresID
   from detalleContenido in contenido.DetalleContenido
      where detalleContenido.Idioma.ds_idioma == idiomaCliente
   select new { detalleContenido, detalleContenido.Archivo };
```

Thank you!